# Customize some text items of a ChoiceBox<>

Tags: java, javafx, styles, customization

I'm having a problem customizing my choice box, I have a list of items that I add to my ChoiceBox in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayOfItems = new ArrayList<>;
myArrayOfItems.add(...);
choiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myArrayOfItems);
```

And I want that some of those items are in bold, for example:

- item 1
- **item 2**
- item 3
- **item 4**

I know that I can customize my choice box with css-like classes but I would like to customize some items in the list not all (in the example below it's item 2 and item 4).

Does everyone know if it's possible to do that with a ChoiceBox ?

TY in advance !
Dylan

Comment: There's no way to do this with a `ChoiceBox`. You can do this with a `ComboBox` (which has similar functionality to a `ChoiceBox`) by specifying a custom cell factory.

Comment: Sorry it's ChoiceBox only I edited the post

Comment: as @James_D already noted, there is nothing in choiceBox that supports your requirement. If you insist on a choiceBox, you need a custom ChoiceBoxSkin (and probably some :odd :even pseudo-states)